# Increment Number OnInsert()

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision

I am trying to increase a field number whenever a new row is added to my table. First I created a variable `lastItem` specified as a Record with Subtype to my Table. Now I created the following Code on the `OnInsert()` trigger:

```
lastItem.FINDLAST;
ItemNo := lastItem.ItemNo + 10;
```

The above code seems not to work on the `OnInsert()` trigger but works for one row when I enter it on the ItemNo - `OnValidate()` trigger.

Any ideas how to get an increasing Number on every new row in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that's Dynamics CRM? The code is a Dynamics NAV C/AL code and you talking about the Item table? In this case let NAV to give you the next number from the No. Series properly.
You can use the same approach in any other table : [related pattern](http://community.dynamics.com/nav/b/navteam/archive/2013/08/05/nav-patterns-of-the-week-no-series)

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm able to define Number Series and can give each new item an increasing number.

Comment: And sorry for the confusion. The question was for Microsoft Dynamics NAV.

Comment: Cool, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

You should stay away from doing direct SQL updates and adding triggers to the DB when using Dynamics CRM as it's not supported.

The appropriate way would be to use a [plug-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328490.aspx) which reads the last value and then does the increment. You'd would register this to run when a new record is created in the system.

You can find some example source code on this CodePlex project: [CRM 2011 Autonumbering Solution](https://crm2011autonumber.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `property` `autoincrement` of the `field`. In this way you increment the `field` one on one in every `row`.